# How to calculate distance from a subject to get the same field of view with different lenses?

Tags: field-of-view, subject-distance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much distance should one move so that a shot that can be framed at xx mm be framed at yy mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30894/how-much-distance-should-one-move-so-that-a-shot-that-can-be-framed-at-xx-mm-be)

I think the question is clear but I will provide an example.

To fill the whole frame with a subject using 60mm lens I have to be `X` meters from it. With 35mm lens I have to be `Y` meters from it. It's obvious that `X > Y` but how to calculate the actual distance (let's say that with 60mm lens, the distance is 1 meter)?

Comment: Isn't it just simply `y = x*(35/60)`? Not sure about this, hence not posting this as an answer.

Comment: @BartArondson This equation occured to me too but I haven't found any proof that it's correct so I rather asked here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is an exact duplicate, but yes object size is directly proportional to focal length so the answer is **x = (60/35) * y**

Comment: Thanks... I'm sorry for the duplicate question, I haven't found the original one when searching...