# How does the depth of field with 50mm f/1.4 compare to 85mm f/1.8 with the same framing?

Tags: depth-of-field, field-of-view, calculations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a formula to calculate DOF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-dof)

Is there an easy way to establish, on paper, which of these two lenses, shot wide open and with the same subject size in frame, would result in a shallower DOF?

I've tried using some of the online calculators but got a bit stuck because the 85 would need a larger camera-subject distance to get the same subject size, but has a longer focal length, but a smaller aperture.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use the Canon 550D and using the [online depth of field calculator](http://www.dofmaster.com/dofjs.html) following calculations can be made:

**50 mm f1.4**

> Focal length: 50mm
>   F-stop: f/1.4
>   Subject distance: 3m
>
> Depth of field
>   Near limit: 2.91m
>   Far limit: 3.1m
>   Total: 0.19m

**85 mm f1.8**

> Focal length: 85mm
>   F-stop: f/1.8
>   Subject distance: 3 * (85/50) = 5.1m
>
> Depth of field
>   Near limit: 4.89m
>   Far limit: 5.12m
>   Total: 0.23m

More on subject distance with different focal lengths can be found in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/30977/9161).

Comment: Thanks. Is it therefore true that subject size in the frame varies proportionally with subject-camera distance?

Comment: I suspect you've got a copy-and-paste typo in your second table: should the focal length be 85mm and the f-stop f/1.8? (I would just edit your answer, but making those changes didn't hit the 6 character limit...)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thanks, was a copy-paste typo indeed.

Comment: @Rich I'm not sure I understand the question. How could it vary *non*-proportionally?

Comment: Well, "proportional" means that if you double one variable, you double the other. In this case, it's certainly *not* proportional: if you double the subject-camera distance, you don't double the subject size in the frame - to a first order approximation, you half it.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that proportionality always meant linear proportionality. But if subject size halves with doubling subject distance, then it's inversely proportional.